# when i install mysql on aws ubuntu error occurs

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, installation, dpkg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X31w.png)

i Had used this command

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server

sudo apt-get purge mysql-common

sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql

sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql.*

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

so many time i try uninstall mysql but i can't fix this error

cuz english is not my first language I can't speak English fluently

but help me everybody .......

Comment: please include `dpkg -l | egrep '(mariadb|mysql)'` output as text by editing this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Uninstall mysql
sudo apt-get remove -y mysql-*
sudo apt-get purge -y mysql-*

# Reinstall mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```